Issues with Passing AWS S3 Credentials as Arguments Using Apache Flink and flink-s3-fs-hadoop Plugin
I am currently working on a project that uses Apache Flink in a Session mode cluster. I have a Jar uploaded to the cluster, which is triggered from another service with arguments, including Amazon S3 credentials. The goal is to establish a source that reads from 53 and writes to Hadoop, utilizing the flink-s3-fs-hadoop plugin.
The plugin has been placed in the /plugins directory of my Flink distribution. However, I'm continuously encountering an error: "No AWS credentials provided". Even though I'm passing the AWS credentials as arguments, it appears they're not being recognized or utilized correctly.
For my business logic, it's essential to pass these credentials as arguments. I've attempted multiple times to shade my Jar differently and added a ‹ property> element of CredentialsProvider to my core-site.ml, but these attempts have not resolved the issue.
Could anyone please help me understand what might be going wrong? Is there a way to make this work without resorting to AWS IAM?
Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
